# How to send multiple elements as React children and position individually where you want

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The structure should look like this:

```
<Modal>
  <Header />
  <Body />
  <Footer />
</Modal>
```

The output should look like this

```
<div>
 <header>
  <Header />
 </header>
 <main>
  <Body />
 </main>
 <footer>
  <Footer />
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This should work just fine, what's your actual problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the passed children by their index and position them.
Here's how to achieve the solution,

```
const Modal = ({children}) => {

 return (
   <div>
    <header>
     { children[0] }
    </header>
    <main>
     { children[1] }
    </main>
    <footer>
     { children[2] }
    </footer>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Passing by props is more safe. Check my answer out.

Answer (score 0):

We have this option to specify different spaces for multiple components. In React, we don't but this action can be done by passing props. Like this:

```js
<MyComponent
  headerComponent={<Header />} 
  bodyComponent={<Body />}
  footerComponent={<Footer />}
>
</div>
```

And in `MyComponent`:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.headerComponent}

      {props.bodyComponent}

      {props.footerComponent}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Modal = ({ children }) => {
return (
<React.Fragment>
  <header>{children[0]}</header>
  <main>{children[1]}</main>
  <footer>{children[2]}</footer>
</React.Fragment>
)};
```

or

```
const Modal = ({ children }) => {
return (
<>
  <header>{children[0]}</header>
  <main>{children[1]}</main>
  <footer>{children[2]}</footer>
</>
)};
```

which does the same things.